# Is food color E-132 indigotine, carcinogenic?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry

I have seen different opinions on food color E-132 Indigo carmine (indigotine, FD&C Blue 2) if it forders cancer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E132 was recently reevaluated by the European Food Safety Authority,
here is the abstract of a 2014 publication in the EFSA Journal on the subject:

The ANS Panel provides a scientific opinion re-evaluating the safety of Indigo Carmine (E132). The Panel observed that Indigo Carmine was poorly absorbed and does not raise concern for genotoxicity. No adverse effects in subacute, chronic, reproduction and developmental toxicity studies, and no modifications of haematological and biological parameters in chronic toxicity studies have been identified at doses less than or equal to 500 mg/kg bw/day. The only report of an adverse effect was in testis with a LOAEL of 17 mg/kg bw/day which would give rise to a safety concern if confirmed. The Panel considered that this study has shortcomings since it is not clear to the Panel whether the adverse effects observed were due to the food additive itself or to impurities and/or contaminants present in the material tested and/or to the conduct of the study. The Panel considered that the current ADI of 5 mg/kg bw/day for Indigo Carmine was applicable to a material with the same purity and manufacturing process as material used in studies without adverse effects on testis (93% pure colouring and 7% volatile matter) and concluded that any extension of this ADI to Indigo Carmine of lower purity and/or manufactured using a different process would require new data which would need to address the adverse effects on testis. The Panel noted that at the MPL, exposure estimates of Indigo Carmine would exceed the ADI for toddlers and children at the high level. Exposure estimates using the available usage and analytical data did not show an exceedance of the ADI for any population groups

https://www.efsa.europa.eu/en/efsajournal/pub/3768

As this was published nearly 4 years and E132 remains approved in the EU, I think it safe to say that E132 is not carcinogenic